# How I can find what values must have `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` for each store/website url from db?

Tags: magento2, database, nginx, base-url

I am transfering a magento website and I have lost nginx settings. But I have full access in the database.

In my case I want to find out upon each store url what values must have the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` fastcgi params.

Therefore I have tried the following query directly from db:

```sql
select 
    store.code,store_website.code,store_group.code,
    urls.*
from 
    store 
join store_website on store.website_id = store_website.website_id
join store_group   on store_group.website_id = store_website.website_id     
left join 
(
    select 
        scope_id,path,value 
    from 
        core_config_data 
    where `path` in (
    'web/unsecure/base_link_url'
    'web/secure/base_link_url'
    'web/unsecure/base_link_url'
    'web/secure/base_link_url'
    'web/unsecure/base_link_url'
    'web/secure/base_link_url'
    'web/unsecure/base_link_url'
    'web/secure/base_link_url'
    'web/unsecure/base_link_url'
    'web/secure/base_link_url'
    ) 
) as urls on urls.scope_id = store.store_id;
```

But the returned columns scope_id, path, value are all null. Therefore how I can map scope_id with nessesary codes from database.

Keep in mind that I have no access to the admin panel either therefore my only option is direct database selections.

Answer (score 0):

A colague of mine tried this query and had some success.

```php
SELECT
    store.code AS store_code,
    store.name AS store_name,
    store_website.code AS website_code,
    store_group.code AS group_code,
    urls.*
FROM
    store
LEFT JOIN store_website ON
    store.website_id = store_website.website_id
LEFT JOIN store_group ON
    store.group_id  = store_group.group_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        scope_id,
        `path`,
        value
    FROM
        core_config_data
    WHERE
        `path` LIKE '%base_url%'
) AS urls ON
    urls.scope_id = store_website.website_id 
ORDER BY
    store_website.sort_order
```